# About cron delete user with meta_key

Tags: functions

i have problems :

- i wanna create cron auto delete user with user meta_key
  Ex: Use have meta_key = not_verified ( in wp_usermeta )

so, i wanna delete all user have meta_key = not_verified !

And i tried code below, but it not working, please help me !

```
function delete_user_not_verified() {
    global $wpdb;
    $held_duration = iwp_option( 'delete_user_not_verified');
    $sql = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->users} WHERE user_id = %s AND meta_key = %s AND (user_registed + INTERVAL %d HOUR) < %s ";
    $users = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql, 'ID', 'not_verified', $held_duration, current_time('mysql')));
    if($users){
        foreach ($users AS $user){
            wpmu_delete_user($user->ID);
        }
    }

    if ( $held_duration >= 1 ) {
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + ( absint( $held_duration ) * 60 * 60), 'iwp_delete_user_not_verified' );
    }
}
```

held_duration

```
array(
                            'name' => __( 'Time to keep draft user (in hours)', 'iwproperty' ),
                            'desc' => __( 'Leave blank if you do not want to automatically delete', 'iwproperty' ),
                            'id'   => 'delete_user_not_verified',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '24',
                        ),
```

iwp_delete_user_not_verified

```
wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'iwp_delete_user_not_verified' );
    $held_duration = iwp_option( 'delete_user_not_verified', '48' );
    if ( $held_duration >= 1 ) {
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + ( absint( $held_duration ) * 60 * 60), 'iwp_delete_user_not_verified' );
    }
```

Comment: Are you actually asking how to delete unverified users automatically?

Comment: Yes Tom ! I have function verify email with new user, and when they signup account, it will create meta key not_verified in usermeta table . So i wanna delete user with 7 day not active account ! but code didn't work !

Comment: It may be easier to go back to the initial problem, rather than trying to fix the solution. By doing that it's not possible to suggest easier working solutions as answers, it kind of backs you into a corner and forces you to focus only on this specific path that *might* be a solution if it's fixed

Comment: There's also a lot of missing pieces in the code in your question, e.g. what is `iwp_delete_user_not_verified`? What does the held_duration mean? How is this function being called? It looks like this code is just a random function that never runs, with none of the connecting glue/pieces to make it run

Comment: Dear Tom ! Thanks so much for your support ! iwp_delete_user_not_verified -> it is cron function auto delete ! And held_duration will get value in admin setting with class value: delete_user_not_verified = 7day ! So, you can know it same: held_duration = time will delete user if not verify , and iwp_delete_user_not_verified is cron function auto delete user ! I was updated code, you can see it !